# AVG warning when compiling with visual studios

Tags: visual-studio-2010, average

Im trying to compile my code in visual studios and every time i do so, AVG gives me a warning saying there is a threat "potentially harmful program hacktool.wun" and shows the file path for the exe that was just created. Any idea why this is happening?[image: This si a screen shot of the issue]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For starters, whether the program compiles or not, try temporarily disabling your antivirus. For the long-term, I suggest adding your program as an exception. The following link provides the steps to exclude files & folders from the detection.

http://www.avg.com/ww-en/faq.num-5187

Answer (score 1):

Check this out, seems its just a mistake in positive detection of AVG

http://forums.cnet.com/7723-19703_102-571744/avg-detects-hacktool-ono-in-hello-world-app/